# Add new column in R using dplyr based on attributes of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr` in R, I'm trying to add a new column based on the attributes of another column.  For example, I have a data frame with thousands of rows of state codes (like `table1`).  Now I want to add a new column called `Region` and assign the state codes to that region (like `table2`). How would that be done in dplyr?

```
table1 <- data.frame(State = c('NY','IL','CA','PA','FL','MI','AZ'))

table2 <- data.frame(State = c('NY','IL','CA','PA','FL','MI','AZ'),
                     Region = c('Northeast','Midwest','West','Northeast','Southeast','Midwest','West'))
```

Comment: do you have a way to lookup which region each state is in? maybe a second table or named vector...

Comment: I think that's what `table2` is supposed to be

Comment: ahh that could be, I assumed that was the expected output

Comment: Yes, the end result will look like table2, but can I create a new column called "Region" (i.e. with 10 regions) and assign each of the 50 state codes to one of the ten regions.

Comment: yes if you have a place to find the value pairings. I usually use a named vector for things like this...`vec <- c("Midwest", "West") %>% set_names(c("MI","CA")); table1 %>% mutate(Region = vec[State])`

Answer (score 1):

This is a `JOIN` problem. Just use `left_join` from the `dplyr` package. In the example below I reordered the states in `table1` to show that it can translate them regardless of the order:

```
library(dplyr)
table1 <- data.frame(State = c('PA','FL','MI','AZ','NY','IL','CA'))
table2 <- data.frame(State = c('NY','IL','CA','PA','FL','MI','AZ'),
                     Region = c('Northeast','Midwest','West','Northeast','Southeast','Midwest','West'))

left_join(table1, table2, by = "State")
  State    Region
1    PA Northeast
2    FL Southeast
3    MI   Midwest
4    AZ      West
5    NY Northeast
6    IL   Midwest
7    CA      West
```